# getting json data from url in c#

Tags: c#, websocket, webclient, webrequest

I'm trying to get json data from the below url in to a C# project into anything, before I can parse/use the data in a chart:

> https://cex.io/api/ohlcv/hd/20160228/BTC/USD

I was actually retrieving the json data by sendin json requests with a websocket but for some reason couldn't get any data with this.So I decided to get the data without providing any json request, as the link was simple.But whatever I tried I ended up with either empty returns or error.At one point I've managed to add a huge chunk of data to the ListBox(seemed like a full html page with some data I needed but I couldn't understand where the whole html code also came from as the link only has json) but that was useless as well. When tried

**WebRequest** with **HttpWebRequest** it didn't recognize WebRequest even with the correct system.net.http and all the rest included.(tried to add manually to References..but they were already checked on the list)
**WebClient** returns empty or useless object or variable type names. **HttpClient** also didn't work but can't remember what it didn't recognize. When I hit the rock bottom I even tried to put a *webBrowser* object and tried to read it from there but then noticed that this shouldn't be that hard, and decided to ask.

Here is what I have done so far:

```
  //HttpClient client3 = new HttpClient();
                             string url = textBox8.Text + listBox3.GetItemText(listBox3.SelectedItem) + listBox4.GetItemText(listBox4.SelectedItem);

                             MessageBox.Show(url);


                             //System.Uri uri = new System.Uri(url);
                             //webBrowser1.Url = uri;

                             System.Net.WebClient client8 = new System.Net.WebClient();
                             //client8.Headers.Add("user-agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/55.0.2883.87 Safari/537.36"); //I dont know if this was needed but seen it on a different example and just added.
                             var html = client8.DownloadString(url);   //returns empty
                             var html2 = client8.DownloadData(url); //adds the line "System.Byte[]"
                             var html3 = client8.OpenRead(url); //adds something like "System.blabla.connectstream"
                             MessageBox.Show(html);


                             listBox1.Items.Add(html2.ToString());
                             listBox1.Items.Add(html3);
```

I'd appreciate if someone could help.

Comment: Your code works and returns that json.....

Comment: https://i.imgsafe.org/14bfd0cb72.jpg  Honestly, it returns an empty messegabox and doesnt add anything to listbox with the first function(html), and adds those 2 lines with the second and last functions, respectively.

Comment: You are using both the bytearray and the ConnectStream wrong. You call .ToString() directly and indirectly, which returns the name of the type of the object.

Comment: http:// is included.It's taking it from a pre-determined textbox. I really don't know how to use these three functions;DownloadStrin, DownloadData and,OpenRead. I've just add them to see which one will work.I add what seem to be most likely to work as it gaved errors, thats why I converted to string, otherwise it wasn't accepting it alltogether .Could you please show me

Comment: Your use of WebClient.DownloadString(url) is fine, and works as intended. Are you sure the url used is correctly put together?

Comment: That's why I put a messagebox so that i can also check and enter it manualy to my browser.they all open on my browser and show the json, but when run, it gave the whole json only once..other times it crashes(mostly) without giving any reason or returns null.

Comment: At here there is my experiment...

[https://github.com/kanpinar/Cex.Io-Api-Winform](https://github.com/kanpinar/Cex.Io-Api-Winform)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@berkdi, you are right. *MessageBox.Show* shows an empty string. But in fact, your *html* string is correct and you can see it by writing the content to a file
like `File.WriteAllText("myfile.txt", html);`.

Below code (when displaying the first 3000 chars of your text) works too

```
System.Net.WebClient client8 = new System.Net.WebClient();
var html = client8.DownloadString("https://cex.io/api/ohlcv/hd/20160228/BTC/USD");
Console.WriteLine(html);
MessageBox.Show(html.Substring(0, 3000));
```

Sorry, You hit a *bug/strange behaviour/bad implementation* of *MessageBox.Show*

**EDIT**

This seems to be the common problem of windows controls that are not designed to display a very long multiline data...

Comment: https://i.imgsafe.org/15a802269d.jpg   the messagebox only returns the full json if it's that date or lower,sometimes that also doesn't work...I have no problem messagebox not taking that much info, I only put it there to see the steps..but as  you can see from the image, it also does not add anything to the listbox..(other than the 2nd and 3rd methods which write to 2nd and 3rd line, and 1st is for the DownloadString, and that returns null, even if it manages to show it with messagebox-that old data)..

Comment: @berkdi it is related with how much data you want to display with MessageBox (possibly with strings without any white spaces). As I said, your code works. Just write the content to a file. (BTW: put a RichtextBox control to your form and set the text property with your data. It will work)

Comment: I've just checked it, it also does not add it to a textbox or any object, just leaves empty, even if it manages to show it with messagebox....All I need is any other type of method to get this data because clearly there is something wrong with my system..I don't need messagebox to display it at all, but I need to put it inside an object one way or another, since I need it in a chart..But it's not even putting the json in textbox.I have to stop it somewhere before parsing,checking etc.

Comment: Thank you, once I takeout that MessageBox, it started to add most data..(most as in, I randomly typed dates, some coulb be closed market days.)

Comment: @berkdi Lesson from this problem: Don't put  these *long*  strings to UI controls if they are not designed to display multiline data.....

Answer (score 0):

Using WebClient is fine

```
var client = new System.Net.WebClient();
var jsondata = client.DownloadString(url);
```

Will do what you want. I have tested it with the url provided, and it does not return an empty string, but the json data.
I think that you might have mangled the url a bit when creating it from your input controls. Can you verify that the url used is actually the same url that you have posted here? Perhaps you are missing an `/` between the last two strings used for creating the url

Comment: I have honestly tried every /|\ and everyother detail. When I write the url to  my browser, it loads it with no problem...any date any year...but on the program, it only returned a full correct json only once from 2016(old data). All the other date inputs (generated by the same function and shown to me via messagebox so that i can check it manually on my browser) freeze and crashed it...although they are structurally the same, when checked on my browser

Comment: Could you also please check with different dates(up to today, no todays data,realtime feed differently) and currency pairs (from btc, ltc,usd,eur) both on your browser and with these methods just changing the link's date and currency-pair part between last //'s